# Unable to change private variables using member functions

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Point {
private:
    int xCord,yCord;

public:
    void setX(int x);
    void setY(int y);
    int getX();
    int getY();
    int rotate(int x, int y, Point p1);
    int moveHorizontally(int x, int a, int b);
    int moveVertically(int y, int a, int b);    
};

int main() {
    Point p1;

    p1.setX(1);     //sets X
    p1.setY(2);     //sets Y

    cout << p1.getX() << ", " << p1.getY() << endl;  //prints current value of X & Y 

    p1.rotate(p1.getX(), p1.getY(), p1);
    cout << p1.getX() << ", " << p1.getY() << endl; 

    return 0;
}

void Point::setX(int newX) {
    xCord = newX;
}

void Point::setY(int newY) {
    yCord = newY;
}

int Point::getY() {       //This will just return the y Cord.
    return yCord;
}

int Point::getX() {      //This will just return the x Cord.
    return xCord;
}

int Point::moveHorizontally(int x, int tempX, int tempY) {
    //Move the point to the right if positive.
    //Move the point to the left if negative.
    int newX = tempX + (x);
    return newX;
}

int Point::moveVertically(int y, int tempX, int tempY) {
    //Move the point up if positive.
    //Move the point down if negative.
    int newY = tempY + (y);
    return newY;
}

int Point::rotate(int tempX, int tempY, Point p1){  
    //(1,2) -->> (-2,1)
    int tempX_DNC = tempX;
    int tempY_DNC = tempY;
    int quadrant;

    if((tempX > 0) && (tempY > 0)) {     //Quadrant 1: x(positive), y(positive)  Then rotates to Quad 2
        quadrant = 1;
        tempX = -(tempY);
        tempY = tempX_DNC;
    } else if ((tempX < 0) && (tempY > 0)) {      //Quadrant 2: x(negative), y(positive)  Then rotates to Quad 3
        quadrant = 2;
        tempX = -(tempY_DNC);
        tempY = tempX_DNC;
    } else if ((tempX < 0) && (tempY < 0)) {     //Quadrant 3: x(negative), y(negative)   Then rotates to Quad 4
        quadrant = 3;
        tempX = -(tempY_DNC);
        tempY = tempX_DNC;
    } else if ((tempX > 0) && (tempY < 0)) {     //Quadrant 4: x(positive), y(negative)  Then rotates to Quad 1
        quadrant = 4;
        tempX = -(tempY_DNC);
        tempY = tempX_DNC; 
    } else {
        quadrant = 0;
    }

    //This will rotate the points 90* to the left.
    //(1,2) will then become (-2,1)
    //I could have if in quadrant1, all are positive, if in quadrant 2 the x would be negative and y would be positive
    //If in quadrant 3 the x and y will both be negative, if in quadrant 4 the x would be positive and the y would be negative
    cout << tempX << ", " << tempY << endl;
    p1.setX(tempX);
    p1.setY(tempY);
    cout <<"x is: " <<p1.getX() <<endl;
    cout <<"Y is: " <<p1.getY() <<endl;
}
```

Code is above.

So I am creating a class Point. Point has 2 private variables xCord, yCord. I want to call the rotate function and have that be able to modify the xCord, yCord but it does not. I am not sure why. I tried passing the Point p1 to the function and to see if that would fix the issue but it did not, I also tried without passing the Point p1 and just having Point p1 inside the function definition.

p1.setX(VARIABLE);
works when it is in main(). but not when I call p1.setX(VARIABLE) inside another member function.

Comment: Please show an example when your `setX` doesn't work. Also see: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Your call is working perfectly well, but I think you should look more carefully at your declarations of your functions to work out what object you're actually changing

Comment: Passing by copy wont wont work , pass by reference to make this work .. But more than this why do you need to pass point object in the first place ? rotate should ideally take only angle ..

Comment: My eyes are bleeding

Comment: you got answers, your problem got solved, now you may accept one of the answers (not necesarrily mine, roberts also tells you what is the problem). However, please for next time read about [mcve] and learn to appreciate the usefulness of a mcve. Your question actually is about pass-by-value vs pass-by-reference and has nothing to do with rotations. The code in your question could be reduced a lot while still demonstrating the issue you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass the point by value:

```
int rotate(int x, int y, Point p1);
                               ^^--------pass-by-value
```

ie. the `p1` inside the function is a copy of `p1` in `main` that gets deleted once the function returns. If you want to change the point that is passed as parameter inside the function then pass it by reference:

```
int rotate(int x, int y, Point& p1);
                            ^^--------pass-by-reference
```

**PS:** ... However, as `rotate` is a member function of `Point` you should probably rather rotate the instance on which you are calling it, change its signature to

```
int rotate(int x, int y);
```

and instead of changing the coordinates of some point passed as parameter do this:

```
 this->setX(tempX);  // this-> not really necessary, just added for clarity
 this->setY(tempY);
```

Alternatively you keep it as is and pass the point that is supposed to be rotated as parameter, but then you should consider making the method `static`.

**PPS**: If you want to change it to pass-by-reference, you have to change the signature in the class declaration to:

```
int rotate(int x, int y, Point& p1);
```

and the definition you have to change to:

```
int Point::rotate(int tempX, int tempY, Point& p1) { /*...*/ }
```

Comment: I am sure that is the correct answer, I am just not able to get it to compile when using that.

Comment: @Juscallmesteve why not?

Comment: error: prototype for 'int Point::rotate(int, int, Point)' does not match any in class 'Point'               
 int Point::rotate(int tempX, int tempY, Point p1){

Comment: error: candidate is: int Point::rotate(int, int, Point&)                                                    
   int rotate(int x, int y, Point& p1);

Comment: @Juscallmesteve you have to change the signature on the declaration and the definition of the method

Comment: So I must be using the pass by reference incorrectly and I need to modify things.

Comment: When I change in both the error it prints out looks as though the p1 in Point p1 is ignored.

Comment: error: candidate is: int Point::rotate(int, int, Point&)

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @Juscallmesteve edited answer, hope it is more clear now

Answer (score 2):

You are passing a copy of `p1` to the `rotate` function. Only this copy is modified.

Answer (score -2):

```
void point::rotate() {
xcord = ycord;
ycord = xcord;
}
```

is all you need for basic rotation

Comment: that is not a rotation (at least not in 2D). And even if it was, after `xcord = ycord; ycord = xcord;` you will have `xcord==ycord` and the second coordinate is lost